# Executing several async function on one object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm curious is it possible to execute function `Function1` and function `Function2` in C# webapi project like in example below.

Both of these functions are on the same class and use `async` and `await` but return different types.

Example code below:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ClassController : ControllerBase
{
    // ...
    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Test()
    {
        var message = await _myClass.Function1().Function2();
        return Ok(message);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Declaration of `_myClass` looks like below:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    // ...
    public async Task<MyClass> Function1()
    {
        // code which uses `await` below
        // ....
        // end of this code
        return this;
    }
    public async Task<string> Function2()
    {
        // code which uses `await` below
        // ....
        // end of this code
        return "some text";
    }
}
```

Comment: Well this doesn't compile so clearly doesn't work. No idea why you need this to be a one liner but you could make it work like this: `var message = await (await myClass.Function1()).Function2();`

Comment: Just curiosity if it is even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Test()
{
    var message = await
        _myClass.Function1().ContinueWith(resultingMyClass => 
        resultingMyClass.Result.Function2());
    return Ok(message);
}
```

But the most obvious solution would be to use the async/await syntax that C# provides:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Test()
{
    var result1 = await _myClass.Function1();
    var message = await result1.Function2();

    return Ok(message);
}
```

If you don't need the result from the first call as input to the second function you can run multiple Tasks in parallel and wait until they have all finished using `Task.WhenAll`.